# Clojure: Inconsistent results using assoc-in

Tags: clojure

Can someone explain what's the reasoning behind the following results using `(assoc-in)`?

```
(assoc-in {:foo {:bar {:baz "hello"}}} [:foo :bar] "world")
=> {:foo {:bar "world"}}

(assoc-in {:foo {:bar nil}} [:foo :bar :baz] "world")
=> {:foo {:bar {:baz "world"}}}

(assoc-in {:foo {:bar "hello"}} [:foo :bar :baz] "world")
=> ClassCastException java.lang.String cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Associative  clojure.lang.RT.assoc (RT.java:702)
```

Apparently I can replace a map and even `nil` with another data type (e.g. String) but I can not replace a data type (e.g. String) with a map, because it need that data type to be already a map.

And how would one work around this? I would like to achieve the following:

```
(assoc-in {:foo {:bar "hello"}} [:foo :bar :baz] "world")
=> {:foo {:bar {:baz "world"}}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`assoc-in`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/assoc-in) is implemented on top of [`assoc`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/assoc). You can replace maps and `nil` because `assoc` works on them:

```
(assoc {} :foo :bar)  ;=> {:foo :bar}
(assoc nil :foo :bar) ;=> {:foo :bar}
```

But `assoc` doesn't work on strings:

```
(assoc "string" :foo :bar) ;=> ClassCastException
```

As an aside, [the definition](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L5596) of `assoc-in` is quite graceful:

```
(defn assoc-in
  ;; metadata elided
  [m [k & ks] v]
  (if ks
    (assoc m k (assoc-in (get m k) ks v))
    (assoc m k v)))
```

If you need to replace a value that `assoc` can't be called on you need to instead act on one level shallower and replace the whole map rather than just the value:

```
(assoc-in {:foo {:bar "hello"}} [:foo :bar] {:baz "world"})
;=> {:foo {:bar {:baz "world"}}}
```

If there are other values within the map that you don't want to lose by replacing the whole thing, you can use [`update-in`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/update-in) with `assoc`:

```
(update-in {:foo {:bar "hello"}} [:foo] assoc :baz "hi")
;=> {:foo {:bar "hello", :baz "hi"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reasoning: The problem is that your :bar is pointing to string "hello" not to a map.
As work around you can use tangrammer's idea

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer by @jbm I looked at the source and came to the following solution (including reimplementing `(assoc-in)`:

```
(defn assoc-in' [m [k & ks] v]
  (if ks
    (let [v' (get m k)
          v'' (when (map? v') v')]
      (assoc m k (assoc-in' v'' ks v)))
    (assoc m k v)))
```

I would be glad if someone could verify this solution.

Comment: I would suggest two changes. First, change `(k m)` to `(get m k)` since not all keys can be used as functions. Second, change `associative?` to `map?` - vectors are associative, but their keys are always integers (indices). At that point I think it will meet your requirements and be reasonably safe but I would also consider using a different name than `assoc-in'`. I don't have any great ideas here, but since it has different semantics than `assoc` it could be confusing to someone working with it later.

Comment: Thanks. I applied your two improvement suggestions. I usually append ' (slightly modified), * (improved), or + (features-added to function to mark if its state.

Answer (score 0):

This code does the work around but I don't know if it will be enough for your requirements

```
(assoc-in {:foo {:bar "hello"}} [:foo :bar] {:baz "world"})
=> {:foo {:bar {:baz "world"}}}
```

Comment: No, sadly not enough as I don't have muh control over the incoming structure.