# Clojure: Implementing the assoc-in function

Tags: clojure

[Chapter 5, Exercise 3](http://www.braveclojure.com/functional-programming/#Exercises) in Clojure for the Brave and True requires:

> Implement the assoc-in function. Hint: use the `assoc` function and define its parameters as `[m [k & ks] v]`.

Although I have found this [solution](https://github.com/dancrumb/clojure-brave-and-true/blob/master/src/clojure_brave_and_true/chapter5.clj) (see lines 39-54), I wondered if there was a different way of doing it. When working on the previous exercise, I found this very clear answer by jbm on [implementing the comp function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21393898/1365720) to be very helpful.

I've been trying to reduce a partial assoc over a conjoined list of keys and apply the returned function to the final value:

```
(defn my-part-assoc [m k]
  (partial assoc m k))

((reduce my-part-assoc {} [:one :two :three]) "val")
```

Needless to say, this doesn't work. I am new to Clojure and functional programming and fear my very basic understanding of reduce is leading me down the wrong path. Please can someone provide a more concise answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shortly after posting, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19694647/1365720), which gets the following definition from the [Clojure GitHub repo](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L5596):

```
(defn assoc-in
  ;; metadata elided
  [m [k & ks] v]
  (if ks
    (assoc m k (assoc-in (get m k) ks v))
    (assoc m k v)))
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this constitutes a duplicate. Although I found my answer on Stack Overflow, I've left my question active as it's quite specific and may help others in same position.

Comment: notice, that unlike the core version, yours would fail with this: `(assoc-in {} [:a :b :c] 1)`...

Answer (score 1):

I think Ooberdan's idea works in case of:

```
(defn my-as-in 
  "assoc val in nested map with nested key seq"                                
  [mp [ky & kysq] val]                                                          
  (if kysq                                                                     
    (assoc mp ky (my-as-in (get mp ky) kysq val))                                  
    (assoc mp ky val)))   

(my-as-in {} [:is :this :hello] 1)
```

gives `{:is {:this {:hello 1}}}` same as `assoc-in`...

Seems neat and idiomatic Clojure and it showed me the way after I got lost in `reduce` or multi arity type solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that doesn't use "assoc-in" which seems to be a requirement:

````
(defn my-assoc-in
  [m [k & ks] v]
  (if (= (count ks) 0)
    (assoc m k v)
    (let [ordered-ks (reverse ks)
          first-m (get-in m (butlast (cons k ks)))]
      (assoc m k (reduce
                  (fn [curr-m next-k] (assoc {} next-k curr-m))
                  (assoc first-m (first ordered-ks) v)
                  (rest ordered-ks))))))```
````

Comment: This is needlessly complicated and definitely not something the author of the book expects a beginner to achieve :(